Error 'IllegalArgumentException: No group with name <host>' in AWS Glue ETL Job from RDS to Snowflake
I've successfully set up AWS Glue with an RDS database serving as the data source and a Snowflake database as the data target. In this setup, I've configured AWS Glue crawlers to catalog the metadata of both the RDS database and the Snowflake database successfully. The RDS crawler effectively scanned and cataloged the metadata of the RDS database, and similarly, the Snowflake crawler successfully completed its task, cataloging the metadata of the Snowflake database.
Now, I've created an AWS Glue ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) job to transfer data from the RDS database to the Snowflake database. For the ETL job configuration, I selected the RDS catalog table as the data source and the Snowflake catalog table as the data target.
However, when attempting to run the ETL job, I encountered the error message 'IllegalArgumentException: No group with name ' during the job execution. Despite the successful creation of both the RDS and Snowflake crawlers and the metadata cataloging process, this error prevents the job from running successfully.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully execute the AWS Glue ETL job to transfer data from the RDS database to the Snowflake database using the cataloged metadata tables. Any insights, best practices, or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
